# MS access Encrypt Users Passwords Stored in User Table (SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

My database is Access front end which is linked to SQL tables, is there a way of Encrypting/Hashing the passwords that are stored in my user table?

I have seen something about Hashbytes and Salt? but not sure how to implement it?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: There is no "built-in" way to do this. You will have to code your own encryption/decryption routines...and hide them from users reach.

Comment: We developed our own in an Access VBA module that worked well.  Depending on if you want SQL Server to do it, or Access, I just did a Google search with "sql server module to encrypt decrypt strings" and found lots of suggestions / code.

Comment: Folks! We  talking about linked tables to SQL server. That means the user id and password are in plain text. You cannot "modify" or encrypt the connection string since then the  connection string will not work. Explain to everyone here  how a SQL server going to accept a "munched" connection string in a linked table?

Comment: Why do you think they're in "plain text"?  You can put them in Hex and then De-Hex them and it works perfectly fine.  We've done this a number of times, I will **guarantee** you that I can send you code that will work.  And Hex isn't "plain text".  Besides, the OP isn't even talking about connection strings, he's talking about passwords.

Comment: NO NO NO. The linked tables to SQL server WILL NOT WORK if they are changed or HEX or anything else. The linked talbes to SQL server ONLY WORK WHEN PLAIN text. You will have to de-crpt and THEN save the un-encropyed strings in the linked tables. At this point in time your tables have plain jaine text and even just hovering the cursor over the  table will show the password.

Comment: Sorry, Albert.  You're 100% wrong.  I wrote the code we use, it works 100% of the time, we had to hex the UID/Password so we would be in compliance since I work for a health insurance carrier.

Comment: Again: how does a linked table work when the password is not in plain view? Are you re-linking on startup? Please explain.

Comment: if the user is just looking to encypt some data in a table, then no problem. However encrypting the user id used in the table link is not possible - the table links must be plain jane text. So the confusing here is are we simply encrypting data in a table, or are we attempting to encytpe the connection strings used in linked tables for that user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to encrypt/decrypt in Access, but it's not hard to create your own.  You can use the old "Zebras" method, by assigning different letters to the alphabet (you could also use some numbers or other ASCII characters instead):

```
Public Function Encrypt(strvalue As String) As String

Const LowerAlpha    As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Const LowerSub      As String = "zebrascdfghijklmnopqtuvwxy" 'zebras
Const UpperAlpha    As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Const UpperSub      As String = "ZEBRASCDFGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXY" 'ZEBRAS

Dim lngi            As Long
Dim lngE            As Long
Dim strEncrypt      As String
Dim strLetter       As String

If strvalue & "" = "" Then Exit Function

For lngi = 1 To Len(strvalue)

    strLetter = Mid(strvalue, lngi, 1)

    Select Case Asc(strLetter)

        Case 65 To 90 'Uppercase
            'Find position in alpha string
            For lngE = 1 To Len(UpperAlpha)
                If Mid(UpperAlpha, lngE, 1) = strLetter Then GoTo USub
            Next
USub:
            strEncrypt = strEncrypt & Mid(UpperSub, lngE, 1)

        Case 97 To 122 'Lowercase
            'Find position in alpha string
            For lngE = 1 To Len(LowerAlpha)
                If Mid(LowerAlpha, lngE, 1) = strLetter Then GoTo LSub
            Next
LSub:
            strEncrypt = strEncrypt & Mid(LowerSub, lngE, 1)

        Case Else 'Do not substitute

            strEncrypt = strEncrypt & strLetter

    End Select

Next

'Now pass this string through ROT13 for another tier of security

For lngi = 1 To Len(strEncrypt)
    Encrypt = Encrypt & Chr(Asc(Mid(strEncrypt, lngi, 1)) + 13)
Next

End Function
```

Then work backwards to decrypt:

```
Public Function Decrypt(strvalue As String) As String

Const LowerAlpha    As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Const LowerSub      As String = "zebrascdfghijklmnopqtuvwxy" 'zebras
Const UpperAlpha    As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Const UpperSub      As String = "ZEBRASCDFGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXY" 'ZEBRAS

Dim lngi            As Long
Dim lngE            As Long
Dim strDecrypt      As String
Dim strLetter       As String

If strvalue & "" = "" Then Exit Function

'Reverse the ROT13 cipher

For lngi = 1 To Len(strvalue)
    strDecrypt = strDecrypt & Chr(Asc(Mid(strvalue, lngi, 1)) - 13)
Next

'Now reverse the encryption

For lngi = 1 To Len(strDecrypt)

    strLetter = Mid(strDecrypt, lngi, 1)

    Select Case Asc(strLetter)

        Case 65 To 90 'Uppercase
            'Find position in sub string
            For lngE = 1 To Len(UpperSub)
                If Mid(UpperSub, lngE, 1) = strLetter Then GoTo USub
            Next
USub:
            Decrypt = Decrypt & Mid(UpperAlpha, lngE, 1)

        Case 97 To 122 'Lowercase
            'Find position in sub string
            For lngE = 1 To Len(LowerSub)
                If Mid(LowerSub, lngE, 1) = strLetter Then GoTo LSub
            Next
LSub:
            Decrypt = Decrypt & Mid(LowerAlpha, lngE, 1)

        Case Else 'Do not substitute

            Decrypt = Decrypt & strLetter

    End Select

Next

End Function
```

Comment: Cannot possible work. We talking about a linked table to SQL server. In access that connection string is plain text and if you modify the user name and pass word then your linked table will fail.

Comment: So how do the links to SQL work when the userid/logon is encrypted using above and thus the uid/password does not match the actual userid/password used by SQL server?

Comment: You're joking, right?  You're an MVP, you should know this!

Comment: If you launch your application without any encypt8on, and look at the connecton strings you will see the uid/password as plain text. If I launch your applation then AGAIN I will see the uid/password as plain text. You suggesting that on startup you de-crypot and re-link and in thus both cases (with or without your suggestion) the simple act of opening  that database will result in the user being able to see the connection strings in full sight.  And any export of the linked tables or  a improper shutdown will mean that un-encypted tables with uid/password in full sight remain in full sight

Comment: No, you have not explain how the table links will work at all. Yes, please do explain.

Comment: Just coming back to this to set the record straight.  First of all, OP never said he needed to encrypt the connection string.  So, right there you're wrong.  However, even if he did, are you familiar with the concept of building connection strings on the fly?  I've got a form I use that allows the developers to switch from Dev server to Test server to Prod server with just the push of a button!  And it will scan the servers for all tables or specific tables, depending on a checkbox click.  This is all done ON THE FLY.  So stop with this nonsense of "You can't use encryption".  You're WRONG.

Comment: @Johnny Bones: Sorry to ask a question that late but I think that everyone who has a connection to the SQL Server and to the ms-access-file (aka the user) is able to get all the passwords, isn't he?

Comment: @Gener4tor - Technically, yes.  But it will be encrypted.  You don't have to use the ZEBRAS encryption method, you can use something more complex, but you're only storing the encrypted version of the password.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you modify or encrypt the connection in the linked table then you will find that you cannot connect to SQL serer. Any suggesting here about having some “encryption” routine will NOT WORK and is NOT relevant since if you modify or mess with the connection strings in your linked tables, then the linked tables will fail. Thus the ONLY possible way this could work is if you take the encrypted connection, de-crept and re-link to SQL server with the plan text connect strings with the user ID and password in plain sight. At this point any user placing their cursor over a linked table will see the user id and password in plain sight (so you gain little if anything by this suggested approach).
The two solutions are:

1 – use windows authentication on SQL server. That means the plain text connections in the Access linked tables do NOT require the user id and password.

2 – use cached logons. This is the RECOMMENDED solution.

Thus you DO NOT include the uid and password in the connection string. Thus there is no need to worry about users looking at the connection string.

What you thus do on startup is execute a logon. The VERY INSTANT you execute a SQL logon, then all linked tables WITHOUT userid/password WILL NOW WORK!

The logon code I use is thus this:

```
Function TestLogin(strcon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.Connect = strcon

   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.
   ' this does assume user has enough rights to query built in
   ' system tables

   qdf.SQL = "SELECT 1 as test"
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True

   Exit Function

TestError:
   TestLogin = False
   Exit Function

End Function
```

How to achieve this is outlined in detail here:

Power Tip: Improve the security of database connections

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections.aspx

It makes LITTLE sense to encrypt the connection string, since then on startup you have to re-link with plain connection strings NOW in sight. And worse is on shutdown you have to re-link the tables gain, else they all be in that linked state with full uid/passwords in plain sight.

Not only is such a process time consuming, but prone to MUCH failure and if the application is shutdown incorrect then the “proposed” schemes here of using custom linking will not only fail, but are impractical solutions.

So using cached logons and passwords results in NOT having to include password and logon in those strings. You can prompt a user for their uid/password, execute the logon and NOW all linked tables like magic will use that logon/pass and do NOT have to be linked and thus you don’t have to store the userid/logon in the application or in the linked table(s) connection strings.